# Symmetric matrix- matrix transpose times matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Is it true that every symmetric matrix $A$ can be written as a product of $B^TB$ for some arbitrary B? This is not really a decomposition, as I know it can be expressed as $Q^T\lambda Q$, but not sure for $B^TB$

Comment: Every positive semi definite matrix can be written as $B^TB$ for some $B$ i.e. as the Gram Matrix of some set of vectors, but not every symmetric matrix.

Comment: Check [Wikipedia: Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: To expand a bit on the first comment, what do you think about $-I_2$ ?